# Plotly: iplot is not working with df.iplot(). How can i make it work?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, iplots

```
enter code here
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import datasets
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import plotly as py
import plotly.tools as tls
py.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
from plotly.offline import iplot


df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3),columns=['A','B','C'])
df1.iplot()
```

i am getting error like 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iplot'
i hope some one could help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use `iplot` anymore. Just set the pandas plotting backend to `plotly` with `pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"`and use `df.plot()`.

Here's a setup using your example:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3),columns=['A','B','C'])
df1.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: @OsSnehithAb Thank you for accepting my answer! We very often see users who get the help they need, and don't even bother to leave a comment or mark a suggestion as the accepted answer. Now that you have actually done exactly that, other users know that there's working solution to this post, and I don't have to keep coming back to it and see what's going on. So it's a very useful and time-saving thing to do. Thanks again!

Comment: i hope u can answer my other question as well, please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390205/how-to-represent-data-in-a-graph-using-matplotlib-plt-plotdf-by-smoothening-th

Comment: @OsSnehithAb That's a [matplotlib] question, and far from my area of expertise. If you'd like to build a similar solution for [plotly] I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the accepted answer from @vestland: if you are plotting several figures, you may not want to use Plotly as the default backend for the whole session.

To use Plotly for a specific figure only:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df1.plot(backend="plotly")  # Plot using Plotly
df1.plot()  # Plot using the session backend (which is "matplotlib" by default)
```